# Computing 16-bit checksum of ICMPv6 header

Tags: python, checksum

I would like to ask if my solution of computing 16 bit checksum according to ICMPv6 protocol is correct. I try to follow [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Control_Message_Protocol_version_6#Message_checksum), but I am not sure mainly about two things.

First is what `the packet length` means - is it the packet length of the whole ICMPv6 packet without checksum, or only the payload? Is it in octets as in IPv6? What is the length of this ICMPv6 echo request?

```
6000                                    # beginning of IPv6 packet
0000 0000 3a00 FE80 0000 0000 0000 0202 
B3FF FE1E 8329 FE80 0000 0000 0000 0202 
B3FF FE1E 8330 

8000 xxxx                               # this is beginning of the ICMP packet - type and checksum
a088 0000 0001                          # from here including this line I compute the length   
0203 0405 0607 0809 0a0b 0c0d 0e0f 1011 
1213 1415 1617 1819 1a1b 1c1d 1e1f 2021
2223 2425 2627 2829 2a2b 2c2d 2e2f 3031
3233
```

Does it mean that the length of the above is 56 octets as I state in the code below?

Then I have problem understanding this (again from wiki).

> Following this pseudo header, the checksum is continued with the
>   ICMPv6 message in which the checksum is initially set to zero. The
>   checksum computation is performed according to Internet protocol
>   standards using 16-bit ones' complement summation, followed by
>   complementing the checksum itself and inserting it into the checksum
>   field

Does it mean I should add the whole ICMPv6 frame with 0000 on the checksum field to the checksum too?

I tried to write a simple program for this in Python:

```
# START OF Pseudo header
# we are doing 16 bit checksum hence quadruplets
## source IP 
sip = ['FE80', '0000', '0000', '0000', '0202', 'B3FF', 'FE1E', '8329']
## destination IP
dip = ['FE80', '0000', '0000', '0000', '0202', 'B3FF', 'FE1E', '8330']
## next header - 32 bits, permanently set to (58)_dec ~ (88)_hex
nh = ['0000', '0088']    
## packet length -> see my question above: (56)_dec ~ (38)_hex
lng = ['0038']
png = "8000 0000 a088 0000 0001 0203 0405 0607 0809 0a0b 0c0d 0e0f 1011 1213 1415 1617 1819 1a1b 1c1d 1e1f 2021 2223 2425 2627 2829 2a2b 2c2d 2e2f 3031 3233".split(" ")

# END OF PSEUDO HEADER

tot = sip + dip + lng + nh + png # from what the sum is going to be counted
stot = sum([int(x, 16) for x in tot]) % 65535 # we are in 16 bits world
rstot = 65535 - stot # wrap around
res = hex(rstot) # convert to hex

print(stot, rstot)
print(res)
check = bin(rstot + stot)
print(check) # all ones
```

that is for the following ICMPv6 ping requests (with IPv6 header):

```
d392 30fb 0001 d393 30fb 0001 86dd 6000 
0000 0000 3a00 FE80 0000 0000 0000 0202 
B3FF FE1E 8329 FE80 0000 0000 0000 0202 
B3FF FE1E 8330 8000 xxxx a088 0000 0001
0203 0405 0607 0809 0a0b 0c0d 0e0f 1011
1213 1415 1617 1819 1a1b 1c1d 1e1f 2021
2223 2425 2627 2829 2a2b 2c2d 2e2f 3031
3233
```

and it gives output:

```
27741 37794
0xe672 # correct?
0b1111111111111111
```

So I should just replace `xxxx` with `e672`. Is it correct? When I try to compute this with wireshark, I get a different answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'll try to address your questions with an example.

Let's take [this sample capture](https://wiki.wireshark.org/SampleCaptures?action=AttachFile&do=get&target=v6.pcap) from the Wireshark wiki so we have the same packet, open it in Wireshark and let's take the first ICMPv6 packet (frame 3).

Note at least one important thing for this packet: the **payload length** for the IPv6 layer is 32 (0x20).

Note: to extract a packet as a string on Wireshark, select the packet and the desired layer (e.g Ipv6) and then: `right click` > `copy` > `bytes` > `hex stream`

**Building the pseudo header**

To calculate the checksum, the 1st thing to do is to build the pseudo header according to [RFC 2460 section 8.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2460#section-8.1).

The checksum is calculated on the pseudo-header **and** the ICMPv6 packet.

> The IPv6 version of ICMP [ICMPv6] includes the above pseudo-header in
> its checksum computation

To build the pseudo header we need:

- Source IP
- Dest IP
- Upper-Layer Packet Length
- Next Header

Source and Dest IPs are from the IPv6 layer.

Next Header field is fixed to 58:

> The Next Header field in the pseudo-header for ICMP contains the value 58, which identifies the IPv6 version of ICMP.

Upper-Layer Packet Length :

> The Upper-Layer Packet Length in the pseudo-header is the length of
> the upper-layer header and data (e.g., TCP header plus TCP data).
> Some upper-layer protocols carry their own length information (e.g.,
> the Length field in the UDP header); for such protocols, that is the
> length used in the pseudo- header.  Other protocols (such as TCP) do
> not carry their own length information, in which case the length used
> in the pseudo-header is the Payload Length from the IPv6 header, minus
> the length of any extension headers present between the IPv6 header
> and the upper-layer header.

In our case, the upper layer (ICMPv6) doesn't carry a length field, so in this case, we have to use the **payload length** field from the IPv6 layer, which is 32 (0x20) for this packet.

Let try some code:

```
def build_pseudo_header(src_ip, dest_ip, payload_len):
    source_ip_bytes = bytearray.fromhex(src_ip)
    dest_ip_bytes = bytearray.fromhex(dest_ip)
    next_header = struct.pack(">I", 58)
    upper_layer_len = struct.pack(">I", payload_len)
    return source_ip_bytes + dest_ip_bytes + upper_layer_len + next_header
```

Code should be called like this :

```
SOURCE_IP = "fe80000000000000020086fffe0580da"
DEST_IP = "fe80000000000000026097fffe0769ea"
pseudo_header = build_pseudo_header(SOURCE_IP, DEST_IP, 32)
```

**Building the ICMPV6 packet**

As mentionned in the [rfc 4443 section 2.3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4443#section-2.3) the checksum field must be set to 0 prior any calculation.

> For computing the checksum, the checksum field is first set to zero.

In this case I use the `type` and `code` fields from ICMPv6 as a signle 16-bit value. The checksum field is removed and the remainder of the packet is simply called "remainder":

```
TYPE_CODE = "8700"
REMAINDER = "00000000fe80000000000000026097fffe0769ea01010000860580da"
```

Building the ICMPv6 part of the packet for checksum calculation:

```
def build_icmpv6_chunk(type_and_code, other):
    type_code_bytes = bytearray.fromhex(type_and_code)
    checksum = struct.pack(">I", 0)  # make sure checksum is set to 0 here
    other_bytes = bytearray.fromhex(other)
    return type_code_bytes + checksum + other_bytes
```

Called as follow:

```
TYPE_CODE = "8700"
REMAINDER = "00000000fe80000000000000026097fffe0769ea01010000860580da"
icmpv6_chunk = build_icmpv6_chunk(TYPE_CODE, REMAINDER)
```

**Calculating the checksum**

Calculating the checksum is done according to [RFC 1701](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1071). The main difficulty in Python is to wrap the sum in a 16-bit quantity.

The input to the `calc_checksum()` function is the concatenation of the pseudo header and the ICMPv6 part of the packet (with the checksum set to 0):

Python example:

```
def calc_checksum(packet):
    total = 0

    # Add up 16-bit words
    num_words = len(packet) // 2
    for chunk in struct.unpack("!%sH" % num_words, packet[0:num_words*2]):
        total += chunk

    # Add any left over byte
    if len(packet) % 2:
        total += ord(packet[-1]) << 8

    # Fold 32-bits into 16-bits
    total = (total >> 16) + (total & 0xffff)
    total += total >> 16
    return (~total + 0x10000 & 0xffff)
```

**Code example**

The code is quite ugly but returns the correct checksum. In our example, this code returns `0x68db` which is right according to wireshark.

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python3
# -*- coding: utf8 -*-

import struct

SOURCE_IP = "fe80000000000000020086fffe0580da"
DEST_IP = "fe80000000000000026097fffe0769ea"
TYPE_CODE = "8700"
REMAINDER = "00000000fe80000000000000026097fffe0769ea01010000860580da"


def calc_checksum(packet):
    total = 0

    # Add up 16-bit words
    num_words = len(packet) // 2
    for chunk in struct.unpack("!%sH" % num_words, packet[0:num_words*2]):
        total += chunk

    # Add any left over byte
    if len(packet) % 2:
        total += ord(packet[-1]) << 8

    # Fold 32-bits into 16-bits
    total = (total >> 16) + (total & 0xffff)
    total += total >> 16
    return (~total + 0x10000 & 0xffff)


def build_pseudo_header(src_ip, dest_ip, payload_len):
    source_ip_bytes = bytearray.fromhex(src_ip)
    dest_ip_bytes = bytearray.fromhex(dest_ip)
    next_header = struct.pack(">I", 58)
    upper_layer_len = struct.pack(">I", payload_len)
    return source_ip_bytes + dest_ip_bytes + upper_layer_len + next_header


def build_icmpv6_chunk(type_and_code, other):
    type_code_bytes = bytearray.fromhex(type_and_code)
    checksum = struct.pack(">I", 0)
    other_bytes = bytearray.fromhex(other)
    return type_code_bytes + checksum + other_bytes


def main():
    icmpv6_chunk = build_icmpv6_chunk(TYPE_CODE, REMAINDER)
    pseudo_header = build_pseudo_header(SOURCE_IP, DEST_IP, 32)
    icmpv6_packet = pseudo_header + icmpv6_chunk
    checksum = calc_checksum(icmpv6_packet)

    print("checksum: {:#x}".format(checksum))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Couple of notes: Your answer packs the checksum as a 32-bit field (with ">I"), but it's supposed to be a 16-bit field ([source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Control_Message_Protocol_version_6#Packet_format)) resulting in ICMP packets that are 34 bytes in length, instead of the 32 you're using for your checksum calculation. It also appears to be assuming that the type of the ICMP packet is 135/NDP, but the OP specifically mentioned 128/Echo Request. Please correct me if I'm wrong, I was trying to use your solution for my own python-based ping program.